# cocos2d CCTableView example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently in the middle of developing a card game using cocos2d. I will need to add a tableview (CCtableview) containing the image of the card and the corresponding statistics of them. Examples on the internet are proving to be scarce - does anyone have a good example i can follow? Any help would be much appreciated - many thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

probably not the cleanest solution but cctableview had a number of bugs and so i just wrote my own implementation

Comment: do you care to make your implementation available for download? I am sorry but as you mention it as an answer, it would be nice if you can make it available. It will help a lot of people... 

Comment: It that supposed to be an answer..??

Comment: Helpful and not helpful. It IS helpful to know that CCTableView has some serious bugs... then, table views are not something you write in 2 minutes :-(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this implementation, it uses a standard table view.

https://github.com/sapusmedia/Sapus-Tongue/blob/master/Classes/HiScoresNode.m